# Call function of the page from component in main layout Blazor

Tags: blazor

I have a `MainLayout` as follows

```
<div>
   <Search>
   @Body
</div>
```

`Search` is a simple component with a textbox and `@Body`, for the sake of this example, is a simple page that loads up a list of organizations. How would I use the value typed in `Search` to execute a the search function in the `@Body\Page`. I have an `AppState` class that I use for simple string component exchanges but I am not sure how to utilize it for something like this or if that's even the most "Blazory" way.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear to me. But I guess you should use

```
   <div class="row"> 
        <Search>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        @Body
   </div>
```

then you can use onload event for call a function